# Bidirectional socket communication between docker container and host

Tags: docker, sockets, port

I want to establish a TCP socket based communication between client and server hosted on a docker and host respectively.

I am trying to run a GCC based socket agent on a ubuntu container running on Docker desktop installed on Windows 10 host. I have done port mapping (-p) to a port where a server runs on Windows 10.

```
docker run -it --name ubuntu1 -p 5997:5997 ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Now when I try to run a java socket server on windows 10 host it is showing error that port is already bind. But I have checked no other application is binding on port 5997.

I found that -p binds the host port already, so another service can not bind this. If I run the socket server on host first then starting container fails.

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5997: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
Error: failed to start containers: ubuntu1
```

What is the correct way to establish a bidirectional socket communication between container and host ,where socket client runs at the container and socket server at the host ?

Comment: This causes Docker to bind to port 5997 and forward port 5997 connections into the container. It seems to work the opposite way from how you expected.